# SignalR can't connect when deployed behind AWS EB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, signalr, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use SignalR on an application hosted in AWS EB, with an application loadbalancer in front.

It works perfectly fine when I test it locally, but when deployed, the websocket can not establish a connection and returns:

"Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: There was an error with the transport."

And

"There was an error with the transport. at WebSocket.o.onerror [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYerror]"

I have tried adding a middleware at the very start of my pipeline, that logs if i get a request for my hub, and this works, so I dont think it is the load balancer or anything AWS Related.

If i call the URL with Postman websocket, I get a status code 400.

I have followed the MS guide and added the configuration for JWT auth

```
jwtTokenOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        // If the request is for our hub...
                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                            (path.StartsWithSegments("/signalr")))
                        {
                            // Read the token out of the query string
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
```

And as I said, it works fine locally. Any suggestions are most welcome

Comment: Any luck in solving this error?

Comment: Yes. It turned out I hadn't enabled websockets as a Windows feature on my windows server hosting the application

Comment: Sorry, I just read your response. Do you know, how to do it on the docker image?

Comment: No sorry, we dont use docker for this application. I have added an answer that describes what i did to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by enabling web sockets for the IIS on the eb instance.
I did this by creating an eb extension with the following command

```
commands:
   01_install_websockets_feature:
      command: "%SystemRoot%\\System32\\dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-WebSockets"
      ignoreErrors: true
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint!  This also solved things for me.  The Load-balancer config was correct, but still SignalR would always fall back to SSE.  I added this to a file called ".config" inside a folder called ".ebextensions" in my VS project.  Make sure that this file is copied to the output directory so it will become a part of the deployment package which gets uploaded to AWS.  Voila, websockets work!